# Removes hash when directing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute

First, the problem:
I have an overview of items, and I want to get directed to a detailpage when clicking on a item. So far so good, the path works and all, but somehow my code keeps directing and removes the hash of the link. My browser(google chrome) tells me "object not found then".

The routing code:

```
.when('/home/:category/', {
        title: "Home",
        name: "home",
        templateUrl: './templates/frontend_home.php',
        controller: "SearchListCtrl"
    })
.when('/detail/:id', {
        title: "Detailansicht",
        name: "detail",
        controller: "DetailController",
        templateUrl: "./templates/frontend_detail.php"
    })
```

I have an ng-repeat of `<tr>`, which link to the detailview like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in responseData | limitTo:limit" ng-click="showDetail(data.id)">
```

And the code in the `SearchListCtrl`:

```
$scope.showDetail = function(detailId){
    console.log("showDetail");
    $location.path('/detail/' + detailId);
}
```

The `DetailController`:

```
lmsApp.controller('DetailController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http){
    $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl){
        console.log(absOldUrl);
        console.log(absNewUrl);
    });
    var ajax=$http.post("./includes/ajax_getDetailInformation.php", {"id": $routeParams["id"]});
    ajax.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.object=data[0];
    });
    ajax.error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log("Ajax failed");
    });
});
```

So, first the link is like:

```
http://localhost/Diplomarbeit/lms_project/#/detail/168?query=violine
```

And than gets (automatically) to something like:

```
http://localhost/Diplomarbeit/lms_project/detail/168
```

I have tried to remove the search query with $location.url($location.path()); before changing the path already, but it doesn't make changes.

I can see the first(working) link in the history, but why does it keep redirecting?

I would appreciate every answer.
Greets,
Force0234

Comment: have you set $location.html5Mode to true

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes

Comment: no I didn't, shoud I?